# Need regex code to get the file path without the file name and extension

Tags: regex

I need to get the file path using regex without obtaining the file name and its extension.

Sample:
c:\testfolder1\testfolder2\abc.pdf

Expected output:
c:\testfolder1\testfolder2\

i tried the regex which obtain the filepath with extension but i need the remaining string of it without having filename and its extension.

i need the opposite of the below regex.

[ \w-]*.pdf

which obtain abc.pdf but instead i need output as c:\testfolder1\testfolder2

Sample:
c:\testfolder1\testfolder2\abc.pdf

Expected output:
c:\testfolder1\testfolder2\

Comment: Something like `.+\\\`?

Comment: Should it always end with .pdf?

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
.*\\
```

It finds everything before the backslash.

Comment: @DINESHkumar Thanks, please feel free to mark my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

RegExp probably isn't what you want to use for this, but here you go:

```
.*[\\/]
```

It should also handle forward slashes in case you have to deal with MacOS or Linux paths.

Comment: I think `.*[\\/]` would be better so that it catches the root slash of something like `/file.pdf`

Comment: You are right, although that is a bit of an edge case. I've made the adjustment.